# Problema ao enviar JSON por ajax para PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Estou há uns 2 dias tentando resolver esse problema, vi umas perguntas daqui do site, mas nenhum resolve o problema. Estou colocando Ajax no login do meu TCC, porém não vai, não dá erro. Já fiz um `file_exists` no caminho do arquivo alvo da requisição e está certo. E se puderem confirmar se estou recebendo certo os dados no PHP, pois os exemplos que vi no site eram apenas com um valor dentro do JSON.

index.php

```
//coloquei só o script porque o código é longo.. (JQuery está incluso pelo bootstrap..
<script>
    function enviar() {

        var usuario = $("[name='txtu']").val();
        var senha = $("[name='txts']").val();
        //está chegando os valores
        console.log(usuario +'/'+ senha);
        $.ajax({
            url: "./controller_php/verificaLogin.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {'usuario' : usuario, 'senha' : senha},
            dataType: "json"

        }).done(function (resposta) {
            console.log(resposta);
        }).fail(function () {
            // está caindo aqui sempre
            console.log("Falha");
        });
    }
</script>
```

verificaLogin.php

```
require_once './model_php/login.class.php';

if ($_POST) {
    $user = json_decode($_POST['usuario']);   
    $senha = json_decode($_POST['senha']);
    session_start();
    //coloquei isso pra testar em uma outra página para ver se estava ocorrendo o post, e na outra página mostra que a variável não foi criada.
    $_SESSION['a'] = $json;

    if (Login::logar($user, $senha)){
        $_SESSION['nome'] = $user;
        $cpf = Login::pegaCPFUsuario($user);
        $_SESSION['tipoUsuario'] = Login::pegaTipoUsuario($user);

        if ($_SESSION['tipoUsuario'] == 2) {
            $_SESSION['log'] = 'ativo';
            return true;
        } else {
            $_SESSION['log'] = 'ativoTecnico';
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Já testou tirando a linha `dataType: "json"`... esta linha está dizendo que o retorno que vc espera é um JSON, e me parece que isso não está ocorrendo e nem é o caso.

Comment: Tirei aqui e continua na mesma coisa..

Comment: Tá caindo no "fail", pode ser que não esteja encontrando o destino

Comment: Outra coisa, `return` em `else` não faz sentido... se o primeiro `return` for executado, com certeza não vai rodar o segundo, por isso não precisa de `else`. E vc está retornando dois `return true` no mesmo IF.. ELSE... bastaria apenas um `return true` após o IF. São redundâncias que poderiam ser evitadas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seu código possui alguns erros

```
if ($_POST)
```

O ideal era verificar se todos os parâmetros que você precisa foram preenchido

```
if(isset($_POST["usuario"], $_POST["senha"]))
```

Essa parte também está incorreta

```
$user = json_decode($_POST['usuario']);   
$senha = json_decode($_POST['senha']);
```

o json_decode espera receber uma string em forma de json, no seu caso, é apenas uma string comum enviada pelo jquery, o correto seria fazer apenas

```
$user = $_POST['usuario'];   
$senha = $_POST['senha'];
```

> ```
> //coloquei isso pra testar em uma outra página para ver se estava ocorrendo o post, e na outra página mostra que a variável não foi criada.
> $_SESSION['a'] = $json;
> ```

Isso ocorre porque o valor passado para o json_decode está incorreto, então ele retorna uma string vazia

esta parte poderia ser editada também

```
    if (Login::logar($user, $senha)){
    $_SESSION['nome'] = $user;
    $cpf = Login::pegaCPFUsuario($user);
    $_SESSION['tipoUsuario'] = Login::pegaTipoUsuario($user);

    if ($_SESSION['tipoUsuario'] == 2) {
        $_SESSION['log'] = 'ativo';
        return true;
    } else {
        $_SESSION['log'] = 'ativoTecnico';
        return true;
    }
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Ficando:

```
    if (Login::logar($user, $senha)){
    $_SESSION['nome'] = $user;
    $cpf = Login::pegaCPFUsuario($user);
    $_SESSION['tipoUsuario'] = Login::pegaTipoUsuario($user);

    if ($_SESSION['tipoUsuario'] == 2) {
        $_SESSION['log'] = 'ativo';
        echo json_encode(["log" => "ativo"]);
    } else {
        $_SESSION['log'] = 'ativoTecnico';
        echo json_encode(["log" => "ativoTecnico"]);
    }
} else {
    echo json_encode(["log" => "não encontrado"]);
}
```

Perceba que eu alterei o

```
return true;
```

para exibir na tela em forma de json o resultado da sua requisição
AJAX não consegue interpretar o "return true" do php, apenas o que está no output, por isso sua requisição não retorna nada, porque return true não exibe nada

O código completo ficaria assim:

```
require_once './model_php/login.class.php';

if(isset($_POST["usuario"], $_POST["senha"])) {
$user = $_POST['usuario'];   
$senha = $_POST['senha'];

session_start();
//coloquei isso pra testar em uma outra página para ver se estava ocorrendo o post, e na outra página mostra que a variável não foi criada.
$_SESSION['a'] = $json;

if (Login::logar($user, $senha)){
    $_SESSION['nome'] = $user;
    $cpf = Login::pegaCPFUsuario($user);
    $_SESSION['tipoUsuario'] = Login::pegaTipoUsuario($user);

    if ($_SESSION['tipoUsuario'] == 2) {
        $_SESSION['log'] = 'ativo';
        echo json_encode(["log" => "ativo"]);
    } else {
        $_SESSION['log'] = 'ativoTecnico';
        echo json_encode(["log" => "ativoTecnico"]);
    }
} else {
    echo json_encode(["log" => "não encontrado"]);
}
}
```